# How does the characteristic of a field work as an exponent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If we are considering a field with characteristic $p > 0$, then it implies that the sum of $p$ 1's is 0. Therefore, $1+1+...+1 = p = 0$. However, when considering $p$ as an exponent, we do not take $p$ to be 0. For example, in $\mathbb{Z_5}$, we have that $2^5 = 32 = 2 \neq 1 = 2^0$. So, $2^5 \neq 2^0$. Why does this not imply that $5 \neq 0$ in the field $\mathbb{Z_5}$?

I'm confused as to why in a field of characteristic $p > 0$, we cannot take $p$ to be 0 in the exponent of a term. I am assuming I am missing something rather simple, but would appreciate if someone could point out what it is I'm overlooking.

Comment: are you confusing field multiplication with field addition?

Comment: Exponents are not, in general, field elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write $2^5$ while working in field $\mathbb{Z_5}$, the symbol $2 \in \mathbb{Z_5}$, but the "$5$" is not an element of the field. It simply a way to avoid writing $2(2)(2)(2)(2)$.

Also, continuing to talk about $p=5$, remember that the elements are most simply labelled as $\mathbb{Z_5}\,=\,\{0,1,2,3,4\}.$ In which case the following is no good:

$$1+1+1+1+1\,=\,5.$$

Rather I'd put:

$$\underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}_\text{$p$ copies}\,=\,0. $$

Comment: A good answer but I would not say categorically that the elements are $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  That is a very common representation but, if you are being strict, the elements are actually equivalence classes e.g. the one commonly called just $0$ is $\{..., -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, ...\}$.

Comment: @badjohn It is not in any way less strict to define operations on the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ to make it into a field of order 5.

Comment: Indeed, it is just that the statement seemed a bit too strong.  This is a common and attractive way to represent the field but it is not definitive, just convenient.  I liked the main point of the answer and I up voted it.

Comment: @badjohn We don't want newbies to think there is a single correct way to represent a finite field, good point. I softened the language. I hope you leave your initial comment in place.

Comment: I like your new version. I can't upvote it but only because I had already.